# Deleting Contact information (Email) for any google Account

Tags: c#, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client, google-directory-api

Scenario is like, I update user primary EmailId, It got successfully updated.
But the old emailid Which the account was registered with, is added as a alias and shown in contact information for that account. I am able to delete alias but the contact information still show the old email id.
Here is the code that is i tried

```
 Aliases objAliases = service.Users.Aliases.List(chkUser.Id).Execute();
            foreach (Alias a in objAliases.AliasesValue)
            {
                service.Users.Aliases.Delete(chkUser.Id, a.AliasValue).Execute();
            }
```

The above code is for aliases, contact information is something i am struggling with.
               The below screenshot will clear the picture.[image]

Circle marked 1. is the email that I need to remove.
Circle marked 2. is aliased that I am able to clean-off.

Answer (score 0):

So, as you've discovered, contacts information can be a tricky within Apps. Users can have aliases as you're seeing but also email addresses (usually external ones) added to their contact info. My guess is: changing the email address is also changing (i.e. adding) the `"emails": []` listed for a user. in their contact info.

To test this, run a [GET for the user](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user) with the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and I suspect you'll see the address still added under the email, not alias section.

You're going to need to make a separate call to delete this from contact information (this will also use the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#update_user)) in addition to the `Users.Aliases.Delete` call.

The separate call could be a PUT request to the user's endpoint with only the data you want to remain. Don't put empty values, delete the entire JSON object

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried that as well. Suppose i have changed primary email for n times. It show n number of aliases While contact information is only the email id which it was registered with( the very first). Even if i delete aliases, no impact on contact information.

Comment: To confirm, when you run the GET, you only see the new primary email listed. The old one is not referenced at all in the response. If that is the case, can you provide a bit more detail where you're seeing the old one? Is it in auto-complete, the Directory, etc.? It's possible, the told address is in personal contacts (My or Other Contacts) due to being messaged before and is now displaying that information for you.

Comment: In the Directory API, the circle marked 2 would be listed under "aliases": [] when you GET the user (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user). The circle marked 1 would be listed under "emails": []. Would you be able to pull this for the same user with the OAuth playground and add the response/request to the description? Sanitize as needed.

Comment: Yup you are right, now problem is Emails is type of object. So dont know what type of data it is containing. How will i update the information in Emails of type object.

Comment: Updated my answer with the options.

Comment: I tried to set emails=[]. request goes successful but no update seen at google end.